# Batch script .exe delete selection

Tags: batch-file

There is a folder which contains some random files:

```
file1.txt
file2.exe
file3.cpp
file4.exe
```

How to SIMPLY display exe files connected with numbers like this:

```
1. file2.exe
2. file4.exe
```

And then I enter the number of the file, which I want to delete.. If it is even possible to do this simply..

Comment: Is it going to be the first file manager written as a Windows batch script? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortest bullet proof solution I can come up with. Like Anders, the DEL statement is disabled by the ECHO command. Remove the ECHO to make the menu functional.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set menu 2^>nul') do set "%%A="
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b *.exe 2^>nul ^| findstr /n "^"') do (
  set menu%%A=%%B
  echo %%A. %%B
)
if not defined menu1 exit /b
set "delNum="
set /p "delNum=Delete which file (enter the number): "
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if defined menu!delNum! echo del "!menu%delNum%!"
```

The only thing I can think of that could go wrong is part of the menu could scroll off the screen if there are too many entries.

Additional messages can easily be incorporated. and an ELSE condition could be appended to the input validation to deal with invalid input.

A few subtle points of the code:

- FINDSTR /N provides incrementing file number. Avoids need for delayed expansion or CALL within menu builder loop. Delayed expansion should not be enabled when expanding a FOR variable containing a file name because it will corrupt names containing `!`.
- `:` is a safe FOR delimiter because a file name cannot contain `:`.
- delNum is cleared prior to SET /P because SET /P will preserve existing value if `<Enter>` is pressed without entering anything.
- Checking for the existence of the variable is the simplest way to validate the input. This is why it is critical that any existing MENU variables are undefined prior to building the menu.
- Must use delayed expansion in IF DEFINED validation, otherwise space in input could crash the script (thanks Anders for pointing out the flaw in the original code)
- DEL target must be quoted in case it contains spaces, even when delayed expansion is used.
- Added test to make sure at least one menu entry exists before continuing. There may not be any .exe files left to delete.

Comment: It barfs if you give it invalid input like "1 2" (1 space 2). Other than that this is pretty sweet. Also, findstr is XP+ IIRC.

Comment: @Anders - Good point about space in input - I hadn't thought of that. Easily fixed above by using delayed expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly pretty but it gets the job done

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
goto main

:addit
set /A end=end + 1
set %end%=%~1
echo %end%. %~1
goto :EOF

:main
set end=0
for %%A in ("*.exe") do (
    call :addit "%%~A"
)
if "%end%"=="0" goto :EOF
echo.&set idx=
set /P idx=Delete (1...%end%)
if not "%idx"=="" if %idx% GEQ 1 if %idx% LEQ %end% (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('set %idx% 2^>nul') do (
        if "%idx%"=="%%~A" (
            echo.Deleting %%~B...
            rem del "%%~B"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `idx` should be cleared prior to SET /P. Your input validation does a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison, so a menu with 5 entries would erroneously accept entry of 11. Removing quotes makes the comparison numeric, but then you are not protected against alpha characters - entry of 1a would be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%f in (*.exe) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set file[!i!]=%%f
   echo !i!. %%f
)
set i=0
set /P i=File to delete: 
del !file[%i%]!
```

Comment: And if a file is named "danger!!.exe" you can watch it blow up in your face, let's just hope it does not delete the wrong file! (Delayed expansion should not be used on filenames IMHO)

Comment: Existing file[] variables should probably be cleared prior to building menu. Also could use some input validation.

Comment: Script continues even if there are no exe files, and target of DEL should be quoted. My original answer had the same problems :)

Comment: @Anders wrote: "Delayed expansion should not be used on filenames". Why? If you suggest that an ! in a file name may cause a wrong Delayed Expansion, that is not true. After the filename is expanded via !file[%i%]! the resulting name is _NOT_ expanded again, so any additional ! don't matters. As a matter of fact, Delayed Expansion is safer than %normal% expansion to manage filenames (normal expansion DO have these problems).

Comment: The problem may arise when _taking_ the filename as the parameter of the FOR command, but not when _using_ that filename... In such a case, the toggling ON/OFF Delayed Expansion technique may be useful.